# Recursively list the files in a specific directory and order according to size

Tags: file-sorting

I'm fairly certain that ls -R will recursively list the contents of the current directory however, I can't work out how to order/sort this in a specifified way.

Can I adjust the ls -R function to order by size?  Or is there another function I can use?

As an extra can this be used on a specified directory without moving to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, just add -S option to ls

```
ls -R -S -l /path/to/folder
```

I have also add -l, to show size of files.

There are also command tree, more human friendly. It need to be installed by `sudo apt-get install tree`

```
tree -h --sort=size /pathtofolder

leonid@DevSSD:~$ tree -h --sort=size / |head -n 10
/
├── [4.0G]  swapfile
├── [3.2M]  core
├── [ 64K]  swap64k
├── [ 16K]  lost+found [error opening dir]
├── [ 12K]  etc
│   ├── [152K]  ld.so.cache
│   ├── [ 53K]  mailcap
│   ├── [ 24K]  mime.types
│   ├── [ 19K]  services
```

Comment: Thanks @LeonidMew I'm a little confused by this (sorry i'm really new to Linux) so is the -S to sort? and the l- to show size?

Comment: -S will sort by size, either it shown in output or not. -l is one of possible ways to show size

Comment: alias to -S is --sort=size

Comment: Excellent thanks.  I'm doing my best to try learn the functions but also understand the meaning behind them so I can adapt them later on where needed.  So thanks for replying it's really helping!

Comment: You can mark this answer by grey check below up/down vote buttons on left, thats how we say thanks there, when answer is useful :) Also, you can find many options for ls by `man ls`